# Is it possible to run airmon-dump a certain number of times?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there a way I can run `airmon-dump` for either a few seconds or for a certain number of refreshes or something to that effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function/option for this in airodump-ng.

But if you're using linux you could run something like this from the bash shell:

```
timeout 5s airodump-ng mon0
```

The example above should kill the process after 5 seconds.