# alternative to timeout for airodump-ng on a Raspberry Pi running Buster

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, timeout, aircrack-ng

I've tried the solution from here:

[Is it possible to run airmon-dump a certian number of times](https://superuser.com/questions/911248/is-it-possible-to-run-airmon-dump-a-certian-number-of-times?newreg=784e8cb7ba8b4d3b9c0759001588e1b3)

but the process doesn't appear to stop. The screen indicates the scan is still running whereas I need it to stop and return to the prompt.

Here's what I've tried:

```
timeout 20 sudo airodump-ng wlan1mon
```

to no avail.